# how do I swap text after comma delimiter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is currently being generated and produces `'LastName, FirstName'`

```
<div id="welcomeMenuBox">
 <spanid="zz4_Menu_t" class="ms-menu-althov ms-welcome-root">
   <a id="zz4_Menu" class="ms-core-menu-root" title="Open Menu" href="javascript:;">LastName, FirstName</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

I would like to swap the text on page load so that it says `Welcome FirstName, LastName` in either JQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method -

```
var currentText = $('.ms-core-menu-root').text();
var arrayText = currentText.split(',');
var newText = 'Welcome ' + arrayText[1] + ' ' + arrayText[0];
$('.ms-core-menu-root').text(newText);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var text = $('#zz4_Menu').text().split(',');
$('#zz4_Menu').text('Welcome ' + text[1] + ', ' + text[0]);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44mCV/)**

Answer (score 2):

***JavaScript*** :

```
var a = document.getElementById('zz4_Menu')
var res = a.innerHTML.split(",")
a.innerHTML = "Welcome " + res[1] + "," + res[0]
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/44mCV/3/)